# How to tear down subscription for unauthorized resource

Tags: node.js, apollo-server, graphql-subscriptions

Below is the prototype of my apollo subscription implementation. Every user can connect to websocket with or without authentication token. But only when they send request, I should be able to either service that request if user is authorized or tear down websocket connection.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    subscriptions: {
        onConnect: async (connectionParams, webSocket) => { 
            if (connectionParams.authToken) {
                try {
                    const user = await authenticate(connectionParams.authToken);    
                    if(user) {
                        return { user };
                    }
                } catch (error) { 
                    return {};
                }
            }
            return {};
        },
    },
    context: async ({ req, res, connection }) => { 
        if (connection) {
            return connection.context;
        }

        let user = null;
        try {
            user = await authenticateFromHeader(req);   
        } catch (error) { 
            console.log(error);
        }
        return { req, res, user };
    }
});
```

Where and how can I tear down it? I assume in Subscription resolvers, but couldn't find how. Is it generally good idea to service authenticated and non-authenticated subscriptions in one connection?

Comment: Is that really necessary? You have an unauthenticated client establish a WebSocket connection, and then you want to disconnect the WebSocket connection when the unauthenticated client makes a request. Why not reject unauthenticated client when establishing a WebSocket connection? That's the official recommendation

Comment: There are public requests, which doesn't require authentication. Until user made request I have no idea if he want something from public domain or resource requiring authentication.